# Update manager refuses update to 22.10 from 22.04

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

Running 22.04 the update manager (Software Updater) after click to upgrade says "Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading."
However `sudo apt update` has been run resulting in

```
Hit:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]      
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
Fetched 110 kB in 1s (213 kB/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
2 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

and `sudo apt upgrade` results in

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use 'pro config set apt_news=false' to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php7.4 libapache2-mod-php8.0
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
```

How can I resolve this situation in order to upgrade to 22.10?

full-upgrade showed 5 packages kept back. So I follwed the advice:

````
libapache2-mod-php7.4:
  Installed: 7.4.29-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidate: 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8
  Version table:
     8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
     8.1.2-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 7.4.29-1+ubuntu21.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
~$ ```
---
Asked to show the full result for apt full-upgrade, I ran '
````

sudo apt full-upgrade

```
again. This time the result was different, but trying to run upgrade to 22.10 gave the same result
<pre>../Upload$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# News about significant security updates, features and services will
# appear here to raise awareness and perhaps tease /r/Linux ;)
# Use &apos;pro config set apt_news=false&apos; to hide this and future APT news.
#
The following packages have been kept back:
  libapache2-mod-php7.4 libapache2-mod-php8.0 libnfsidmap1
The following packages will be upgraded:
  firmware-sof-signed rsync
2 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.
Need to get 1 223 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1 168 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 rsync amd64 3.2.3-8ubuntu3.1 [404 kB]
Get:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 firmware-sof-signed all 2.0-1ubuntu4 [819 kB]
Fetched 1 223 kB in 0s (3 769 kB/s)<font color="#CDCD00">            </font>
(Reading database ... 288644 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rsync_3.2.3-8ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rsync (3.2.3-8ubuntu3.1) over (3.2.3-8ubuntu3) ...
Preparing to unpack .../firmware-sof-signed_2.0-1ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking firmware-sof-signed (2.0-1ubuntu4) over (2.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Setting up firmware-sof-signed (2.0-1ubuntu4) ...
Setting up rsync (3.2.3-8ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
.../Upload$ sudo update-manager
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
.../Upload$</pre>  
So I can still not upgrade to 22.10.
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt full-upgrade`. If that fails, then run `apt policy libapache2-mod-php7.4` and post the complete output in your question.

Comment: If "*full-upgrade showed 5 packages kept back*", then please add that complete output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to question 675876/cant-install-some-packages-depends-x-but-x-is-to-be-installed useful.

After downgrade of libapache2-mod-php8.0, that is `sudo apt install php8.1-common=8.1.2-1ubuntu2.8` I could upgrade all other packages. And then start the upgrade to 22.10 without problems.